# CollectionViewCell sizing problems

Tags: ios, swift, resize, row, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view in my app. I am using `UICollectionViewDelagateFlowLayout` protocol. the cells are sizing just how I want them to, which is displaying 2 cells per row. But when I go into landscape it displays 3 cells per row.

question: How can I force my app to display two cells per row no matter what happens?

Comment: Show your layout methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two collectionView' delegate method in your class

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/ 2 - 10, height: 100) // chnage as per your need ...10 is the space between cell
    }

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    myCollectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: yes. I dont know how to accept this answer. also do you know how i could change the background of the first two cells?

Comment: check this for how to accept answer :https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/343629

Comment: if you want change color of first two cell then you can put condition in cell forRowAtIndexpath  if indexPath.row ==0 {}

Comment: This condition works and changes the background color but when I switch to landscape or scroll it highlights a different one

Comment: then you need to track that indexPath.....declare indexpath' s instance and set value in in this condition.

Comment: Im sorry i'm a newbee in swift. could you show me the code I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the collection view is being resized when you go into landscape so there is enough room for three cells per row. Why don't you disable the resizing of the collection view on orientation change.

Otherwise you will probably need to write your own UICollectionViewLayout.

Comment: that sounds great. I'm sorry I am kind of a newbee so could you show me how to disable the resizing

Comment: How are you setting up your UI. Is it through storyboard?

Comment: I make my UICollectionView and constrain it in storyboards

Comment: Are you using constraints or auto-resizing flags? If you are using constraints you could add a size constraint to limit the dimensions of the collection view